# Reading multiline data in Kotlin

Tags: string, kotlin, input

The problem is:

Several strings are given, e.g:

```
1 2 3
5 8 5
1 2 2
```

What is the best way to read all of them in Kotlin? And if strings look like that:

```
1 2
5 8 5
1 2
```

How to read them correctly without kludge?

I knew how many strings I'll get, so I've tried this (n — number of strings)

For the first example:

```
for (i in 0 until n) {
   val (a, b, c) = readln().split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
}
```

For the second example:

```
for (i in 0 until n) {
  val string = readln().split(' ').map { it.toInt() }
  val (x, y) = string
  var z = 0
  if (string.size > 2) z = string.last()
}
```

Comment: Please show your desired outputs.

Comment: I want to read the whole string and put each number in variable. So if I read the first string "1 2 3" I want to put them in variables x, y, z and then work with them depending on a problem

Comment: So for each line, you want to assign the 3 numbers on that line to `x`, `y` and `z`, and if there are fewer than 3 numbers, assign only `x` and `y` (or only `x`), and the rest with 0?

Comment: yes! but it's also interesting is it possible to assign only x and y (or only x) and that's all?

Comment: It’s also going to depend on whether you need all of the numbers outside of the loop or if you only need to process them line by line and feed them to some output from inside the loop. And depending on what you’re producing with them it may be silly to assign them to named variables instead of handling them together as a collection. Is your logic going to be completely different for two items versus three items?

Comment: The last three lines of your second example can be simplified to `val (x, y, z) = string + 0` It adds a zero to the end of the list so if we had only two items, there’s now a third item with value zero. And if we had three items already the 0 at the end is excess and will simply be ignored.

Comment: I don't think so.. According to a task the first number is a type of operation and the last 2 or 1 (depending on a line) are numbers that I need to process. So `1 2 3` means "do operation 1 with 2 and 3" and `3 5` means "do operation 3 with 5". I can give you the full description of the task so you will clearly understand what I mean